# cmake resolving false path

Tags: linux, qt, build, cmake, kde-plasma

I set up my kdevelopment environment (framework, apps) in my home directory and have all qt-5.9 related things (libs, headers etc.) set up system-wide.
Now I tried to install `akonadi-17.04` via cmake. This however crashes with the following error:

```
$ cmake -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=~/Dev/kf5-frameworks-5.36 -DCMAKE_MODULE_PATH=~/Dev/kf5-frameworks-5.36 ..
...
CMake Error at /usr/lib64/cmake/Qt5Sql/Qt5SqlConfig.cmake:27 (message):
The imported target "Qt5::Sql" references the file

 "/usr/include/qt5/QtSql/5.9.1"

 but this file does not exist.  Possible reasons include:

  * The file was deleted, renamed, or moved to another location.

  * An install or uninstall procedure did not complete successfully.

  * The installation package was faulty and contained

     "/usr/lib64/cmake/Qt5Sql/Qt5SqlConfig.cmake"

  but not all the files it references.

Call Stack (most recent call first):
 /usr/lib64/cmake/Qt5Sql/Qt5SqlConfig.cmake:71 (_qt5_Sql_check_file_exists)
  CMakeLists.txt:40 (find_package)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

Why is cmake resolving to `/usr/include/qt5/QtSql/5.9.1`? In `/usr/include/qt5/QtSql` only headers can be found

Comment: It depends on how did you install that and what OS you are on. Maybe you should try KDE Craft.

Comment: I'm using opensuseleap42.2. A lot of other applications are building just fine, e.g. kmix. However this doesn't

Comment: You might be missing some `-devel` package.

Comment: Ok thanks, is there anyway to figure out which one is missing?

Comment: It seems like on suse, there aren't qt5-devel packages available. Might this be the reason?